# No puedo extraer datos de una columna tipo JSON en PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

soy nuevo usando PosgreSql y su campo tipo de dato Json.
Quiero extraer datos de una columna tipo json para insertarlos en una tabla con el fin de normalizar una base de datos.

la columna tipo JSON se llama "info" y un ejemplo de un registro es el siguiente:

```
[ { "major" : "International business", "end" : "2007", "name" : "Annamalai University", "degree" : "Master Degree", "start" : "2005", "desc" : "" }, { "major" : "Mechanical Engineering", "end" : "1990", "name" : "Bharathidasan University", "degree" : "Bachelor Degree", "start" : "1990", "desc" : "" } ]
```

el codigo que intento utilizar es el siguiente:

```
SELECT id,(json_array_elements(info)->>'education')::json ->> 'key'  AS key1 from perfiles where id = 1252710;
```

el resultado que quiero obtener:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me marca entre otros errores lo siguiente.

> ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array
>     CONTEXT:  parallel worker

¿Como debo hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor manera de usted convertir un JSON de datos para columnas es crear un type en el PostgreSQL. Abajo sigue un ejemplo con una tabla e sus datos:

```
CREATE TABLE teste (
    id integer,
    datos json
);

INSERT INTO teste VALUES (1, '{ "major" : "International business", "endn" : "2007", "name" : "Annamalai University", "degree" : "Master Degree", "start" : "2005", "descc" : "" }');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES (2, '{ "major" : "Mechanical Engineering", "endn" : "1990", "name" : "Bharathidasan University", "degree" : "Bachelor Degree", "start" : "1990", "descc" : "" }');

create type json_datos as (major varchar(60), endn integer, name varchar(60), degree varchar(30), start integer, descc varchar(60));

select id, (json_populate_record(null::json_datos, datos)).*
from teste;
```

Caso usted no quiera crear un type, puede crear las columnas de manera manual:

```
select  id, 
    datos ->> 'major' as major, 
    datos ->> 'endn' as endn,
    datos ->> 'name' as name,
    datos ->> 'degree' as degree,
    datos ->> 'start' as start,
    datos ->> 'descc' as descc
from teste;
```